# Adding dates to dates using dateadd

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking through problematic code someone else wrote (I am unable to contact them, they've long since moved on) and I found out the code was having trouble because of dateadd.  Online, everywhere I look, they say the format for dateadd is (interval, number, date).  It is written in this code as (interval, date, date).

More specifically:

```
Dim UnixTime As String
Dim HumanTime As String
For i = 2 to 37
UnixTime = Sheets("Current Values").Cells(i, 4) 'cell(2, 4) is "12/31/2016  7:15:00 AM" without quotes
HumanTime = DateAdd("s", UnixTime, CDate("12/31/1969 08:00:00 PM"))
```

This code has worked in the past, so I never had cause to look at it, but now it's just outputting a time, with no date attached to it.  To add to the mystery, halfway through troubleshooting it, it seemed to mysteriously start working.  I'm not complaining about it working, but next time it whines at me, I'd like to know where to start looking.  How does vba convert a date to a number?  Is there a more appropriate function than dateadd for this purpose?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "output"? On the worksheet or in the variable?  BTW, that code plays fast and loose with it's data types - I'd refactor to treat dates as dates, not strings.  You'll end up with much more robust code.

Comment: Also, `DateAdd` is adding seconds. A quick fix could be to wrap `HumanTime` in a `Format` function: `Format(HumanTime,"mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS")`

Comment: HumanTime comes out to be just a time, with no date attached to it.  12:00:00 AM, iirc, though I can't check now because the code isn't complaining anymore.  Which part of the code is bad?  Doesn't CDate ensure that is a date?  Absent the middle part, which is...bad...

Comment: If you already have "12/31/2016  7:15:00 AM" in the target cell, why are you doing this conversion at all? [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) is measured in seconds from epoch (which should be a `Long`).

Comment: I don't know why the conversion is being done, the code is awfully commented.  There's a few ifs afterwards - if it's January 1 - March 10, or November 5 - December 31, then `HumanTime=HumanTime - (1 / 24)`.  I don't even understand still how you can just subtract a fraction from a date though.  That just doesn't make sense to me.  It should just be the next day at 7:15 AM.  Do I have anything to lose by just replacing this whole section with `dateadd("d", 1, cells(i,4))`, and making that the new cell?

Comment: In VBA dates are a number of days starting from 31-Dec-1899 as 1. Times are fractional parts of those numbers, so subtracting 1/24 is subtracting one hour.

Answer (score 0):

Since your UnixTime is a string, you will need to CDate that as well

```
HumanTime = DateAdd("s", CDate(UnixTime), CDate("12/31/1969 08:00:00 PM"))
```

I agree with Comintern that it would be better to work with these as dates rather than strings.